# Get the product name {title} in the low stock email?

Tags: cartthrob

The default low stock email template only output the product ID number.

I've tried {title} in that template, but it does not get parsed.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the title using entry id and channel:entries

```
<p>Low Stock Warning</p>

{exp:channel:entries channel="your_products_channel" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

<p>Low stock notification for item {title} (id number {entry_id}).</p>

{/exp:channel:entries}

<p>Stock level is currently at {inventory}</p>

<p>Please restock this item and update the stock level.</p>
```

Was trying to do this myself and just tried this and it works.

**N.B.** I think {inventory} needs to be outside {exp:channel:entries}